# Changing batch size in Spark Streaming during the execution

Tags: python, batch-file, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to vary the batch interval duration in Spark Streaming (i.e., depending on some tests in the code) so that it does not stays the same for all the computation time?

When coding in Python, for instance, the batch interval duration is the second argument in

`StreamingContext(sparkContext: SparkContext, batchDuration: Duration)`;

e.g., `ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)`,

and as far as I know it is not going to change during the execution.

Is it possible in Spark to make it mutable *during* the computation, i.e. accordingly to the output of some tests?

A dumb example of a possible use: in the [class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/network_wordcount.py) `newtork_wordcount.py`, increase the batch interval duration in case of a particular string (or line) in the previous batch interval.

I hope I have been clear enough!

Thanks to anybody who will try to help! Have a nice day! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the batch size in spark streaming at least that is what Tathagata Das said in one of his talks.

Comment: It is in fact true, I asked TD himself. By the way, it appears not being in the roadmap yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this [paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~yz2561/dynamic_batching.pdf) by TD may answer your question. He tried to use dynamic batch interval and get better result.